# Crystal Reports Multiple Joins

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm currently working on implementing some logic into a Crystal Report, and I'm wondering if what I am doing is actually working the way I believe it's working.

the way the logic I'm working with is broken up is like this:

```
(
   Table1
   Inner Join
      Table2
   On Table1.record1 = Table2.record2
) group1
Inner Join
   Table3
On group1.record2 = Table3.record3
```

Rather than create a view or procedure that does this, I was wondering if I could just do this in Crystal Reports itself by Including Table1, Table2, and Table3 in the report and then Linking them by Linking Table1 to Table2 via record1 and record2 and then linking Table2 and Table3 on record2 and record3.

The reason I'm not sure if these are equivalent is because of the first inner join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in crystal reports in 2 ways:

1. Use the query directly in the crystal reports using `add command` after creating the database connection.
2. Take the 3 tables and join those with inner joins in links tab.